# Pandas Flatten a Complex Multi-level column dataframe

Tags: pandas

I initially had a dataframe with column ID and Date, i wanted to find the first and last Date entry for every ID.

Therefore i applied an aggregation function:

```
df.groupby('ID').agg({'Date':['first','last']})
```

I have a dataframe in the following form:

[image: DataFrame]

```
print(df.columns)
>> MultiIndex(levels=[['Date', 'ID', 'difference'], ['first', 'last', '']],
       labels=[[1, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

I want to flatten this dataframe such that i get the dataframe in the following manner:

[image]

I tried using `df.reset_index(level=[0])`
and also used `df.unstack()` but couldn't get the desired result.

Any leads regarding on how to solve this problem?

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: not me, I think reason is for pictures - data is not possible copy. Is possible add your code for create your DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael I had a dataframe with column id,and date, so to get this dataframe i applied `df.groupby('id').agg({'Date':['first','last']})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need change aggregate function for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns with specify column for aggregate and list of aggregating functions:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'id': [23] * 5 + [35] * 5})  
print (df)
        Date  id
0 2017-04-03  23
1 2017-04-04  23
2 2017-04-05  23
3 2017-04-06  23
4 2017-04-07  23
5 2017-04-08  35
6 2017-04-09  35
7 2017-04-10  35
8 2017-04-11  35
9 2017-04-12  35

df1 = df.groupby('id')['Date'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
print (df1)
   id      first       last
0  23 2017-04-03 2017-04-07
1  35 2017-04-08 2017-04-12
```